# creating order with custom options programatically in magento via php

Tags: php, ce-1.9.0.1

While creating order programatically,if custom options are passed through a function in the form of customoption={label:[xl],value:[5]}, the order should be created with these custom option fields.
    I am using the below code:

```
            foreach($orderproduct->id as $key=>$item) {    
            $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product'); 
            $product->load($item);
            $quoteItem = Mage::getModel('sales/quote_item')->setProduct($product);
            $quoteItem->setQuote($quote);
            $quoteItem->setQty($orderproduct->qty[$key]);
            $quoteItem->addOption($existentOptions['additional_options'][] = array(
           'label' => $optiontitle, // Title of custom option field
           'value' => $customvalue,  // Value of custom option field
            ));
            $quoteItem = $existentOptions->getItem();
            if ($existentOptions = $quoteItem->getOptionByCode('additional_options'))
            {
                $orderItem = $additionalproduct->getOrderItem();
                $options = $orderItem->getProductOptions();
                $options['additional_options'] = unserialize($existentOptions->getValue());
                $quoteItem->setProductOptions($options);
             }
            $quote->addItem($quoteItem);
        }
```

This is creating the order, but product is not getting added.A blank morder is created in which there is no custom product.
    Kindly please help me.

Comment: I've found that Amasty's recent blog post works perfectly for Magento 1.9. Seems to be rather easy to modify to your own needs. Found here: https://blog.amasty.com/creating-magento-order-programmatically/

Comment: Here's the code for OrderGenerator.php https://git.amasty.com/magento/order-generator/tree/master